# 0x8badf00d: urlSessionDidFinishEvents called after didCompleteWithError

Tags: ios, swift, background-task

I started a background task, queued up some upload tasks, stopped the background task, and then both didCompleteWithError and urlSessionDidFinishEvents were called. The completion handler wasn't set, and I don't think handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession was called.

I have one theory - maybe I queued up some upload tasks with my app, uninstalled and reinstalled my app, and a previous session from the uninstalled instance of my app happens to finish right after tasks from the currently installed version. I'm not sure if that's possible...

I'm trying to avoid the 0x8badf00d errors, and the underlying issue seems to be that urlSessionDidFinishEvents can get called without handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession getting called. I'm trying to understand how that could happen - this usually works fine for me. So, how could the situation I laid out above happen, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Stopped a background task? Why and how? If you've configured a background task, by definition your app isn't even running. Perhaps you're using background tasks incorrectly?

Comment: 8badf00d is a watchdog error - It typically means you have deadlocked.

Comment: @matt I queue up background session tasks and then end the background task - iOS should either finish the uploads in that app session or not, it shouldn't matter to me, right?

Comment: @Paulw11 not calling a completion handler for a background session will also cause this - I suspect that's the issue.